# Conditional inline text in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am trying to produce an automated html output using Rmarkdown. Some of the reports contain data for 2022 only and some contain data for 2017 and 2022.

I want to conditionally print text based on what data is available for that clinic.

I initially create a dataset where for each variable a 0 will be printed if there are no observations:

```
data_from_2017 <- as.data.frame(colSums(!is.na(clinic_subset17))) %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as.data.frame()
```

Then this is the inline code I am using:

```
`r 
if (data_from_2017$lifesatisfaction == 0) {
  Their current life satisfaction was rated on a scale of 1-10 (with 10 representing the highest satisfaction). The average life satisfaction score for your clinic was `r life_sat` in 2022.
} else {
     Their current life satisfaction was rated on a scale of 1-10 (with 10 representing the highest satisfaction). The average life satisfaction score for your clinic was `r life_sat17` in 2017 and `r life_sat` in 2022.
} `
```

However, it fails to parse - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible option to achieve your desired result using `cat()`, chunk option `results='asis'` and a custom helper function:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: html_document
date: "2023-12-04"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

```{r}
data_from_2017 <- data.frame(
  lifesatisfaction = 0
)

life_sat <- 8
life_sat17 <- 6
```

```{r}
life_sat_helper <- function() {
  sentence <- paste(
    "Their current life satisfaction was rated on a scale of 1-10 (with 10 representing the highest satisfaction).",
    "The average life satisfaction score for your clinic was"
  )
  if (data_from_2017$lifesatisfaction == 0) {
    cat(sentence, life_sat, "in 2022.\n")
  } else {
    cat(sentence, life_sat17, "in 2017 and", life_sat, "in 2022.\n")
  }
}
```

```{r, results='asis'}
life_sat_helper()
```

```{r}
data_from_2017 <- data.frame(
  lifesatisfaction = 1
)
```

```{r results='asis'}
life_sat_helper()
```
````

[image]

Comment: Great thanks that works. However when I use proportions it adds a space behind it (so looks like 5 % when I want it to be 5%). Is it possible to stop that happening?

Comment: Sure. `cat()` as `paste()` by default uses a space as separator. To prevent that you can do `cat(..., sep = "")` but in that case you have to add the spaces manually for other parts of the string.

Comment: Thanks - super helpful. If I wanted to bold some of the text within the cat function - how would I do that?

Comment: @VickiLatham Wrap in `**`, e.g. `"Their **current** life satisfaction was rated"` or `cat(sentence, "**", life_sat17, "**", ...)`.

Comment: Unfortunately the first part works with 'current' being bolded but the 'life_sat17' is not as it just prints the stars out in the text.

Comment: @VickiLatham Aw. Sorry. The issue is that `cat` like `paste` adds a space. Instead we have to wrap in `paste0`, i.e. `cat(sentence, paste0("**", life_sat17, "**"), ...)` or add the spaces for the whole text manually and set `sep=""`.